# Python - TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and i'm having trouble with iterating in a list. This is the piece of code I'm having trouble with:

```
for x in list(xrange(instance.nbw)):
         sddpbw.append(choice(sddpfw))
print sddpbw

for t in reversed(list(xrange(instance.T))): 

    if t>0:
        for u in sddpbw:
            # for n in list(xrange(1,instance.NUMPATHS+1,passo)):
            for n in pairs[t][u-1]:
                if n != u:
                    for p in instance.HP:
                        x[n-1][t-1][p-1]=x[u-1][t-1][p-1]
```

I have a previous list (sddpfw) and want to chosse some elements from it and create another list (sddpbw).
The exit is:

```
[4, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "PDDE.py", line 179, in <module>
       x[n-1][t-1][p-1]=x[u-1][t-1][p-1]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

But if I comment the section that creates the variable sddpbw and create it mannually it works fine:

```
# for x in list(xrange(instance.nbw)):
    # sddpbw.append(choice(sddpfw))
sddpbw=[4, 2]
print sddpbw
```

I can´t figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What do you think `x` _should_ be in the second `for` loop?

Comment: Why the `for x in list(xrange(...))`? when `for x in xrange(...)` will do just fine? Not to mention `for x in reversed(list(xrange(...))):`.. That can be handled by `for x in xrange(instance.T - 1, -1, -1):` instead.

Comment: Indeed `list(xrange(x))` removes the memory savings of using `xrange` over `range`.

Comment: `__getitem__` this method you call from list when you do like this `var[0]`. On this code you do the same but for integer variable and you get this error. What is the `x`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. As I said, I'm a beginner. I'll replace the list(xrange(x))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reset your `x` variable on this lines. When loop finished, you get `x` as some integer number.

```
for x in list(xrange(instance.nbw)):
     sddpbw.append(choice(sddpfw))
```

For example

```
>>> c = [1,2,3]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
>>> for c in xrange(1, 3):
...     print(c)
... 
1
2
>>> c
2
```

You need change this `x`to anything else name.

```
for _ in list(xrange(instance.nbw)):
   sddpbw.append(choice(sddpfw))
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the problem